# Migrate question to external sites - move bug to tag(project) issue tracker

Tags: feature-request

Some questions are just bug reports, would it be possible to select external site for migration when closing it?

As example here is such question: [rvm install fails searching for binary rubies on a vagrant box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17497228/rvm-install-fails-searching-for-binary-rubies-on-a-vagrant-box) - and it's not first time I'm closing "bug report" because it is not a question and just stating that something is broken.

I was thinking about:

- for tag allow assigning a bug tracker link
- when closing question allow to migrate to the tag bug tracker if given
- integrate with most common mass project sites like https://github.com

This would help both in closing bad questions and the project in question.

Answer (score 5):

This would require a gigantic amount of effort  for very, very little gain - and it may even be actively harmful to the external target sites in question because it sends askers of low quality questions to innocent small projects with much less community moderation manpower than Stack Overflow has.

Bug trackers have quality requirements of their own. To properly file a bug, you need categorization, tagging, step-by-step reproduction instructions, platform info, etc. How can Stack Overflow automate the process of opening a new bug in any meaningful way, seeing as data will be required that is not present in the original SO question - at least not in computer-readable form?

Also, the *bug will probably already exist in the bug database*. How would Stack Overflow be able to detect that, and what should it do when there is a duplicate?

Just point the OP to the right venue in the comments. Or, if it's a really badly formulated question, don't - the likelihood that a user who filed a bug report in the wrong place is actually going to make a good, useful contribution to the bug database isn't that big.

Comment: I agree with the effort reasoning, but I can not agree with the rest: 1) not every project maintainer watches SO for related questions, not forwarding the problem means the y do not know about it; 2) the smaller project is the less quality requirements it enforces on users for a bug report; 3) assumption that the bug already exist is false because users turn in to SO instead of reporting a bug; 4) Even I have asked to report the bug few times only one of them was actually reported back to issue tracker, which gives really low ratio.

Comment: @mpapis so tell the OP to manually report the bug, or do it yourself if they don't. Problem solved, no? (Also if people would only ask on SO because they did prior research and didn't find anything, it wouldn't have 5 million questions. Most of those are duplicates of each other.)

Comment: I do not feel like it's solved, this works only in case where someone monitors for such questions, without at least showing a "close because it's a bug for: (issue trackers from tag)" this will leave hanging questions, which for other users do not have to look like bugs, giving that option explicitly will allow other users to handle it properly ... or at least consider that possibility, if forwarding it is to much just give the link.

Comment: @mpapis to implement this, Stack Overflow would have to build connectors to dozens of different bug tracker APIs  to post bugs that would be worthless anyway because they still lack information that those trackers need - bug category, error description, etc. Having SO do this automatically is *completely insane.* The problem can be solved by simply posting a comment directing the user to the right place to report their problem.

Comment: as I mentioned on the end of my last comment: or at least consider that possibility, if forwarding it is to much just give the link.

Comment: @mpapis that's a fair idea, but I think it's hard to do automatically. There'd have to be a database of bug tracker links that someone would have to keep up to date. I don't see how it could be doable

Comment: I guess you have a database already, I was thinking it would be just a new column for tag table, projects do not change bug tracker often, in fact it's so rare I would assume project is not used at all if it changes the tracker few times

Comment: @mpapi mmm, I've seen examples to the contrary with some Open Source projects. I really think this is an issue that is best addressed by prolific users in the community who know what's up and can point the user to the best place to ask.

Comment: ok then, I do not think that's a rule, more like an exception to change the tracker often, as I do not agree with most parts of your answer I can not accept it (although I accept the part that would be to big effort)

Comment: @mpapis fair enough. You can leave the question without an accepted answer no problm, many feature requests don't have one

Comment: Just wanted to show example where reporting a bug was not even considered an option => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17740882/bash-line-234-rvm-warn-command-not-found-and-curl-1-protocol-https-not-sup - if we had at least option when closing question => "This is a bug, report to project issue tracker" - it does not even has to link any side, but would show that option